# How to turn on wifi on Dell Inspiron 17R 5737

Tags: wifi, drivers

I have a Dell Inspiron 17R 5737 running Slackware 14.1. My wifi doesn't work, and I think I've narrowed the problem to the wifi switch which I assume is off because the corresponding light is off. I've searched online and seen any number of 'solutions' but none seem to work. Oh, and wlan0 doesn't exist, it says no wifi device. 
  I don't have this problem with Scientific Linux, but I haven't figured out how they do it.

TIA.

Bev

Comment: Linux has some type of wifi driver, You can start with `lspci` and specify your cheap of your wifi , and then install your related driver.

Comment: I think I already did:  lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net :    It shows my ethernet controller and my NEtwork controller.

Comment: use `lspci|grep -i wireless`